# best way to secure simple wysiwyg with php

Tags: php, security, xss, wysiwyg

I have added a simple wysiwyg editor in my website. (it only allows B / I / U - no more)
I currently store all content as html in my database - but it's simple to add `<a onclick='...'>` or other malicious code)

What is the best way in PHP to parse this input safely?
How to implement `<b></b>`, `<i></i>` and so on as whitelist and encode everything else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### HTMLPurifier

I'm just going to throw this one out there and probably get the inevitable lashing. I would not use `strip_tags` to secure your WYSIWYG form... **ever** (Unless you want to piss off your users).

It won't secure your form, and you may be **killing** your user's experience.

[Chris Shiftlett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/mar/allowing-html-and-preventing-xss) in his blog post wrote an excellent paragraph

> I detest commenting on blogs where my comment is passed through something like strip_tags(), effectively mangling what I'm trying to say. It reminds me of using an IM client that tries to identify smilies and replace them with images, often making responses difficult to decipher.

### Another Reason

Someone else in another answer also wrote this which I like:

```
  $str = "10 appels is <than 12 apples";
  var_dump(strip_tags($str));
```

The output I get is:

```
string '10 appels is ' (length=13)
```

I personally would not use **anything** other than HTMLPurifier

### HTMLPurifier

[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Try a demo here: http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php

And look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226406/is-markdown-with-strip-tags-sufficient-to-stop-xss-attacks)

Comment: Maybe you could recommend the correct settings for HTMLPurifier? Playing around with it in the demo it usually breaks the 12 apple example as well.

Comment: How does this work for you? http://bit.ly/mZ3txc I believe you need to collect the errors to be safe. That should work?

Comment: Yeah, that's the only setting I found, I just don't understand it well. Why "collect errors"...? :)

Comment: But please please please keep your installation of HTMLPurifier up to date, as with any software. This is /such a hard problem to solve/ Exploits are found all the time as browsers and the use of HTML changes over time. HTMLPurifier is probably not perfect and may still let script though - here's a recent set of vulnerabilities from just a few months ago. http://secunia.com/advisories/43907/

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip_tags()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

> string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

The second parameter is a list of allowable tags; just list `'<b><i><u>'` and the rest will be stripped.

**Do note** that as deceze mentioned:

> This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you
>   allow using allowable_tags, including the style and onmouseover
>   attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that
>   will be shown to other users.

So it doesn't offer full protection from malicious code by itself!

Comment: `This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you allow using allowable_tags, including the style and onmouseover attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that will be shown to other users.`