# Instert html/text to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, text, sql-injection

I am using TinyMCE to allow users to edit the content of certain pages, the problem is that I should store html tags, along with class="" -es and ..etc.
How should I defend the application against SQL injection, and store the html tags? (main problem is the " -s, It is messing up the mysql query)

In nutshell, I don't know how to add the $_POST (which is a text) to the insert_to_content() function.

```
    $html = "";
    $url = "";if (isset($_GET["page"])) {$url = safesql($_GET["page"]);}
    $sqlSelectPageText = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM content WHERE name="'.$url.'" LIMIT 1');
    $pageText = mysql_fetch_array($sqlSelectPageText); /**/ $sqlSelectPageText = ""; 
    if (isset($_GET["edit"]) and isset($_POST["text"])) {
        insert_to_content($url,I_SHOULD_DO_SOMTHG_WAAA($_POST["text"]));
        header('Location: admin.php?page='.$url);
    }

    $html .= '<div id="editor1div">';
    $html .= '<form action="admin.php?page='.$url.'&edit" method="post">';
    $html .= '  <input class="formsSubmit" type="image" src="images/yep2.png" alt="Save" />';
    $html .= '<p>Content:</p>';
    $html .= '  <textarea id="editor1" name="text">';
            $html .= '      '.$pageText["text"]; /**/$pageText = ""; 
    $html .= '  </textarea>';
    $html .= '</form>';
    $html .= '</div>';


    echo $html;

function insert_to_content($whatPage, $text) {
    if (mysql_query('UPDATE content SET text="'.$text.'", lastdate=NOW() WHERE name="'.$whatPage.'"')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}

function I_SHOULD_DO_SOMTHG_WAAA($text) {
           //what should i do with it?
}
```

EDIT:
@CaNNaDaRk:
I am trying to use your work, but never used PDO (or OOP PHP) so.
 So, is it possible that I don't have this function? :D
 "Class 'PDO' not found in.."
 `

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$sqlHost;dbname=$sqlDb;$sqlUser,$sqlPass"); 
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE content SET text=:text, lastdate=NOW() WHERE name=:name');
$stmt->execute( array(':text' => $html, ':name' => $whatPage ) );
```

Comment: You can start with using prepared statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to avoid injection.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize your HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255158/best-way-to-secure-simple-wysiwyg-with-php/7255179#7255179

Comment: Please note that HTML is not special case regarding SQL injection.

Comment: Yes it is possible that you don't have it. What version of PHP/MySQL are you running (phpinfo() can help http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)? Look at this for other infos about PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: I must also note that SQL injection isn't the only vulnerability to defend against. Be sure to look into [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) can prevent injection and help you with the " issue.
A little example based on your code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE content SET text=:text, lastdate=NOW() WHERE name=:name');
$stmt->execute( array(':text' => $html, ':name' => $whatPage ) );
```

Execute method also returns bool so you don't have to change your code much.

Comment: I added a comment to your question. I googled a little about "Class 'PDO' not found in.." and found some useful links, maybe you can try that too. In example http://softexpert.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found-in-tdbconnectionphp/ this could help

Comment: I had to add "extension=php_pdo.dll;
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll;" to my php.ini

Comment: But I cant get the PDO to connect to my sql. It always returns an error.

Comment: Tried with new PDO('mysql:host='.$sqlHost.';dbname='.$sqlDb, $sqlUser, $sqlPass ); ? Any errors inside apache log? Did you restart apache?

Answer (score 3):

Its not only the tinyMCE text but rather **your whole script that may lead to SQL injections**. Either use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for every parameter you insert into your query or think of using **prepared statements** such as [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

1. use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as suggested
2. when displaying content, use `htmlspecialchars()` when adding content into the textarea to prevent XSS.

Comment: special chars are important against JS injection

Answer (score 0):

You basically need different quoting for html/sql target formats. **There is nothing like "universal quoting"**. When quoting, you **always quote text for *some particular output***, like:

1. string value for mysql query
2. `like` expression for mysql query
3. html code
4. json
5. mysql regular expression
6. php regular expression

For each case, you need different quoting, because each usage is present within different syntax context. This also implies that the **quoting shouldn't be made at the input into PHP, but at the particular output**! Which is the reason why features like `magic_quotes_gpc` are broken (**never forget to handle it, or better, assure it is switched off!!!**).

So, what methods would one use for quoting in these particular cases? (Feel free to correct me, there might be more modern methods, but these are working for me)

1. `mysql_real_escape_string($str)`
2. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, "%_"))`
3. `htmlspecialchars($str)`
4. `json_encode()` - only for utf8! I use my function for iso-8859-2
5. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, '^.[]$()|*+?{}'))` - you cannot use preg_quote in this case because backslash would be escaped two times!
6. `preg_quote()`