# Escape from XSS vulnerability maintaining Markdown syntax?

Tags: php, escaping, xss, markdown, markup

I'm planning to use [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) in my web page. I will keep users input (raw, no escaping or whatever) in the database and then, as usual, print out and escape on-the-fly with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

This is how it could look:

`echo markdown(htmlspecialchars($content));`

By doing that I'm protected from XSS vulnerabilities and Markdown works. Or, at least, kinda work.

The problem is, lets say, `>` syntax (there are other cases too, I think).

In short, to quote you do something like this:

`> This is my quote.`

After escaping and parsing to Markdown I get this:

`&gt; This is my quote.`

Naturally, Markdown parser do **not** recognize `&gt;` as “quote's symbol” and it does **not** work! :(

I came here to ask for solutions to this problem. One idea was to:

First, parse to Markdown, — then with [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) remove “bad parts”.

What do you think about it? Would it actually work?

I'm sure that someone had have the same situation and the one can help me too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a certain website has that exact same situation. At the time I'm writing this, you have 1664 reputation on that website :)

On Stack Overflow, we do exactly what you describe (except that we don't render on the fly). The user-entered Markdown source is converted to plain HTML, and the result is then sanitized using a whitelist approach ([JavaScript version](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js), C# version [part 1](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html), [part 2](http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags)).

That's the same approach that HTML Purifier takes (having never used it, I can't speak for details though).

Comment: So thanks! :) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1226814/458610) also was pretty helpful for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using is not secure.  Consider, for instance, this example: "`[clickme](javascript:alert%28%22xss%22%29)`".  In general, don't escape the input to the Markdown processor.  Instead, use Markdown properly in a safe mode, or apply HTML Purifier or another HTML sanitizer to the output of the Markdown processor.

I've written [elsewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14674/971) about how to use Markdown securely.  See the link for details about how to use it safely, but the short version is: it is important to use the latest version, to set `safe_mode`, and to set `enable_attributes=False`.

Comment: if you are talking about "enable_attributes=False" and "safe mode", the latest version of markdown.php is from january and I can not locate those settings. Is it just me or what are people talking about. I came across this several times in different posts and those where all more recent.

Comment: @Richard, read the link in my answer, where you'll find lengthy details on how to use Markdown securely and answers to your question.