# 100% safe way of storing html in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, code-injection

I'm working on a project where the public (so everyone) is allowed to insert HTML through TinyMCE for their own project page. Since everyone is allowed to use this feature, I need a 100% safe way of inserting the TinyMCE output into my database, and showing it on another page just as it was inserted by the user.

XSS, SQL injection and all that other crap is not what I want on my new website! I could do htmlentities -> htmlspecialchars and later on use htmlentities_decode, but is this 100% safe, and it is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Allowing users to write raw HTML that is then displayed to other users is practically begging for exploits.  Avoiding SQL injection is trivial; just use prepared statements.  Avoiding XSS in this scenario is tricky (impossible?).

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/ - HTMLPurifier

Comment: I agree with @OliCharlesworth, it's almost impossible to prevent XSS in your case.

Comment: I think the best is to use PDO and prepare the parameters using [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). No need to escape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL injection is in most cases easily avoided with the use of prepared statements.

XSS is more difficult if you're planning to allow users to post HTML markup.  You need to remove all `<script>` tags, all `on*` attributes from tags, all `javascript:` urls, and even then that's probably not fully guaranteed to make the input HTML safe.  There are libraries such as [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) that can help, but so long as you allow HTML, you're at risk of letting something malicious through.

You could use a library that implements something such as markdown or wikitext instead.  This severely limits what users can enter, whilst still letting them mark the content up to an extent.  It's not fullproof (people can still just post links to malicious sites and hope users click through to them,which some will be naive enough to actually do), and you'll not be able to use a rich editor such as TinyMCE without some sort of plugin, but it's a much simpler job to sanitize markdown than it is to sanitize HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It is not doable. You think to filter so that's a good point but in the end it won't be possible to lock it down totally if you accept html. Take a look at things like bbcode, markdown etc. to see some alternatives.

If you decide to accept HTML code it's not just filtering what needs to be done, even encodings can generate serious security issues. Search for UTF-7 for example to see what kind of issues. See some examples here: http://www.webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt

Comment: It sure is doable, just use a HTML filter with a safe whitelist. I'm kind of surprised the only upvoted answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Even with a whitelist it is possible to generate tags by using smart tricks. Also think about encodings etc. Even HTML purifier which is a very well known and well though class had security issues in corner cases. It sounds nice but it's just too hard to consider it safe. Since the amount of options possible there are lots- and lots of corner cases which should all be covered. It is not possible to oversee all options, so that's why it's a security issue.

Answer (score -3):

Storing and showing the HTML are two different things.

For **storing** the HTML in MySQL, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is enough, and will protect you from SQL injections.

For **displaying**, it depends. You want users to be able to write HTML, yet you want to be protected from XSS attacks and such, so you should use a filter like HTMLPurifier (this is what Stackoverflow does). You only need to do this once you retrieved the HTML from the database.

You never need to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlentities_decode()`.

Comment: so you store an content and then you filter? why not filter and then store..

Comment: Because if the user wants to edit their HTML later, you don't want them to show them the processed text. You can circumvent this by using two columns in MySQL, one for the raw HTML and one for the filtered HTML. I think this is out of the scope for this question, though.

Comment: "this is what StackOverflow does" - but StackOverflow doesn't render arbitrary HTML anyway...

Comment: @Artefact2, are you being serious? Of course it doesn't

Comment: @Artefact2: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites.

Comment: @Oli: my point exactly. They use HTMLPurifier-like filters to enforce this whitelist.

Comment: @Artefact2 why you don't want them to see processed output since that is what they will get in the end.....

Comment: @Artefact2: Citation needed!  I would assume that they have a custom parser which deals with this, given they only handle a trivial subset of the language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618540/615776

Comment: @Artefact2: Which confirms my assumption...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I think now I see the misunderstanding here. You're saying `no it doesn't` to rendering arbitrary html, while Artefact2 is saying `yes it does` to html purifying. You're both right.