# Sanitize Markdown from XSS

Tags: php, html, xss, markdown, code-injection

I use Markdown for provide a simple way for write posts to my users in my forum script.
I'm trying to sanitize every user inputs, but I've a problem with Markdown's inputs.

I need to store in database the markdown text, not the HTML converted version, because users are allowed to edit their posts.

Basically I need something like what StackOverflow does.

I read [this article](http://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/) about XSS vulnerability of Markdown. And the only solution I found is to use HTML_purifier before every output my script provides.

I think this can slowdown my script, I imagine output of 20 posts and running HTML_purifier for each one...

So I was trying to find a solution for sanitize from XSS vulnerabilities sanitizing the input instead of the output.

I can't run HTML_purifier on the input because my text is Markdown, not HTML. And if I convert it for get HTML I can't convert back for turn into Markdown.

I already remove (I hope) all HTML code with:

```
htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($text));
```

I've thinked about another solution:

When an user is trying to submit a new post:
Convert the input from Markdown to HTML, run HTML_purifier, and if it find some XSS injection it simply return an error. 
But I don't know how to make this nor I know if HTML_purifier allows it.

I've found lot of questions about the same problem there, but all solutions was to store the input as HTML. I need to store as Markdown.

Someone has any advice?

Comment: 1. Remove **all** tags from the input with `strip_tags()`, 2. sanitize input which are used in attributes like the [link](javascript:alert('xss')): 3. consider running `htmlspecialchars()` on the input before turning converting into HTML and output. Should be fairly safe no? I mean only you control what HTML tags are going to be used so as long as you strip them all in the input and sanitize attributes you got full control over XSS.

Comment: It doesn't prevent the bug showed in my link.

Comment: Hm that's pretty discouraging if it doesn't detect tags over multiple lines..

Comment: Can you explain your sentence pls? I don't understand it.

Comment: The vulnerability or bug I assume you refered to in your link says html tags are not properly stripped if you break it over multiple lines.

Comment: oh, yes exactly, Markdown can generate HTML code not wanted when it parse Markdown code... And this is the main problem. I think is a Markdown bug, right?

Comment: Well the bug seems to be in the [PHP Markup Parser](http://michelf.ca/blog/2007/php-markdown-no-markup/) (mentioned in your link). Markup itself is just a syntax specification or a fake language if you may. It all depends on how you parse it.

Comment: The solution could be patch this vulnerability, but I don't know how to patch it by myself and I can't find a bug tracker for Markdown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Run Markdown on the input
2. Run HTML Purifier on the HTML generated by Markdown. Configure it so it allows links, href attributes and so on (it should still strip `javascript:` commands)

---

```
// the nasty stuff :)
$content = "> hello <a name=\"n\" \n href=\"javascript:alert('xss')\">*you*</a>";

require '/path/to/markdown.php';

// at this point, the generated HTML is vulnerable to XSS
$content = Markdown($content);

require '/path/to//HTMLPurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);

// put here every tag and attribute that you want to pass through
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|title],blockquote[cite]');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

// here, the javascript command is stripped off
$content = $purifier->purify($content);

print $content;
```

Comment: Thank you, but... isn't enough find all occurrences of "javascript:" and remove them? Without html_purifier but just with a regex.

Comment: @FezVrasta Not a chance. There are dozens of ways to avoid using the string "javascript" — https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet. Furthermore, you can't even parse HTML with regexes.

Comment: Ok, so... I convert markdown to HTML, sanitize it with HTML_purifier, and after that... How can I store my Markdown in database?

Comment: Store the original untouched markdown, just parse and sanitize it when you need to display it. For performance's sake, you may want to cache the rendered HTML (or store it in the DB).

Comment: Store two versions, markdown and sanitized HTML (2nd one for caching purposes I guess?) When the user wants to edit his post, just serve him the markdown version. The malicious code has no effect if it's escaped and inside a textarea

Comment: I think should be better prevent any bad text to be stored in database, by blocking the user who is trying to inject it. Isn't better? How can I use HTMLPurifier for check presence of XSS injections and run `die()` in the case it finds some bad code?

Comment: No. I often type `href="javascript:"` by mistake. Why would you block me? :) Just use prepared statements when storing any kind of data in the db, and sanitize it for display when you need to display it...

Comment: Really? Please... If someone is trying to hack me I want to block him, not to sanitize his attempt...

Comment: And how do you know that he is trying to hack you? This is security by obscurity. You may end up blocking a legit user. What if SO blocked me for posting the code above?

Comment: Your text will not be modified by HTML_purifier, so, if I use HTML_purifier for check if the text is safe instead using it for sanitize it, you wouldn't be blocked. _(We can chat about this in a separated chat)_

Comment: But if you're using the purifier, you *are* sanitizing it. And you might as well print the result. I understand that HTML Purifier can be slow and this is why you hesitate using it, but that's why you should cache the result (you can move this to chat if you want to talk more about it...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24643/discussion-between-fez-vrasta-and-one-trick-pony)

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

```
$text = "> hello <a name=\"n\"
> href=\"javascript:alert('xss')\">*you*</a>";


$text = strip_tags($text);

$text = Markdown($text);

echo $text;
```

It return:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>hello  href="javascript:alert('xss')"&gt;<em>you</em></p>
</blockquote>
```

And not:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>hello <a name="n" href="javascript:alert('xss')"><em>you</em></a></p>
</blockquote>
```

So seems that `strip_tags()` does it works.

Merged with:

```
$text = preg_replace('/href=(\"|)javascript:/', "", $text);
```

The entire input should be sanitized from XSS injections. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The html output of your markdown depends only on the md parser, so you can

1. convert your md to html, and sanitize the html after that like described here:

   [Escape from XSS vulnerability maintaining Markdown syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616906/escape-from-xss-vulnerability-maintaining-markdown-syntax)
2. or you can modify your md parser to check every param which goes to html attribute for signs of xss. Ofc you should escape for html tags before parsing. I think this solution is much faster than the other, because by simple texts you should usually check only urls by images and links.